# Output is not displaying in HTML format after transforming the xml result using xslt when the attribute name contains special character

Tags: html, xml, xslt

My xml has just 1 value as name =RDXXX-LOWER_DECK, value=10 mm. When this is transformed using xslt I get output correctly as below:

```
 <table>
 <tr valign="top">
 <td width="200">RDXXX-LOWER_DECK</td>
 <td width="200">10.000000000000 mm</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

But when I replace RDXXX-LOWER_DECK as RDXXX||LOWER_DECK (hyphen is replaced with double pipe) I don't get the output. Empty value is printed and name is printed as "Attribute" .

```
 <table>
 <tr valign="top">
 <td width="200">Attribute</td>
 <td width="200"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

KIndly let me know how to retain || in the output.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example input and an executable stylesheet.

Comment: @mplungjan The linked answers have absolutely nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My xml has just 1 value as name =RDXXX-LOWER_DECK, value=10 mm.
> But when I replace RDXXX-LOWER_DECK as RDXXX||LOWER_DECK (hyphen is replaced with double pipe)...

If by that you mean that you have an XML like this:

```
<RDXXX-LOWER_DECK>10mm</RDXXX-LOWER_DECK>
```

and you changed it to look like this:

```
<RDXXX||LOWER_DECK>10mm</RDXXX||LOWER_DECK>
```

then you no longer have a well-formed XML document. The `|` character is not allowed in an element [name](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name).

> ... I don't get the output. Empty value is printed and name is printed as "Attribute" .

That is strange, because you *should* have been getting an error.

Comment: Ok if not "|" , any other special character also is not working except for "-" (hyphen)

Comment: I provided a link to the XML specification that lists explicitly which characters (or ranges of characters) are allowed in an element name. All other characters are "not working". Note that the list is even more restrictive for the first character. Also some older processors might conform to an older specification which also allows less characters. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Basically customer wants some special character between RDXXX and LOWER_DECK in the final output (Table will be in HTML format) . First column will have attribute name as  RDXXX||LOWER_DECK and in 2nd column , it will have its value displayed say 10mm. But while transforming the attribute name "RDXXX||LOWER_DECK" using xslt, special characters are not being processed.

Comment: I don't see why your customer cares what the name of an element is. And I am not sure what qualifies as "a special character". Why is a hyphen or a period not satisfactory? If they want something that looks like a vertical line, they can use the `&#448;` LATIN LETTER DENTAL CLICK character. But this is meaningless because you can output whatever result you want using the original, unmodified  XML as the input.

Comment: hyphen is already used in some of the attribute's names. So they do not want to use here again. Anyway thanks Michael, by reading the XMl specification link I have got some clarity and I will discuss of using period instead of ||.